# git show changes done by last 10 commits by me or anyone in a folder

Tags: git

I have a git repository in which I have a folder . In this folder multiple people makes changes . I have recently made few commits in that directory .

I want to

```
 1) view all changes that I have done in last 10 commits in that directory
    (ie changes done by me only)
```

and

```
 2) view all changes that anyone has done in that directory in last 10 commits .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
git log -p -10 yourdir/
```

Add `--author=yourLogin` to limit to your changes.

This differs from just [listing the changed files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245448/6309).

Comment: in one of my commits id: 5  i had removed a line  and in next commit id: 6  i had removed my line . Still the  command above shows that the line as removed

Comment: @MAG that is a separate question. My answer was for your initial question.

Comment: oh .. i got it .. Sorry . That is indeed a separate question but can you help me here . Accepting your answer as i was initially confused.

Comment: i am interested in knowing in totality my changes as a single view not showing commit ids one by one

Comment: @MAG it will be clearer that way. In your new question, you can reference this one, but also add more details regarding those two commmits.

Comment: please find the new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340105/git-show-changes-done-by-last-10-commits-by-me-or-anyone-in-a-folder-as-a-consol